# How to disable log file for py2exe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, py2exe

I've created a small script using `Python` and `PyQt4`, I converted it to `exe`. But there's some cases in my script that I'm not handling so a `log` file being created while using the program. So I wanna disable creating this `log` file.

How can I do that?

Here's my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    windows=['DumbCalculator.py'],
    options = {
        "py2exe": {
            "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"],  
        }
    },
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to do that.

I went to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\py2exe` and then opened `boot_common.py` file and commented the 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 63, 64,65 lines and saved it.

I run py2exe again and tried the program works great. It makes a log file but doesn't run its annoying prompt. It worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid editing the package, *and* avoid creating the log file, by adding the following to the top of your main .py file:

```
import sys
if sys.frozen == "windows_exe":
    sys.stderr._error = "inhibit log creation"
```